# VMware Vmotion 5.1 fails at 51% , Between two identical new vmware servers

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

We've been trying to deloy two new CISCO UCS C220 M3S servers ESXi Hosts.
the installation went smooth en perfectly.

We added both servers in a ESXi (5.1 update 2) cluster.
this to perform vmotion and auto migration of vm's between 2 esxi hosts.

But we are encountering some issues with migration vm's between both hosts 
(same hardware same setup same settings)

When migrating a live vm machine between server a and b it fails at 51% with following error:
"A general systemerror occured: the source detected that the destination failed to resume"

The Vmware Vmotion validation before migrating is succesfull.

This issue only occurs when the vm's are running, one's they are inactive / shutdown there are no issues with migrating the vm's back and forward between server a and b.

The storage also keeps active and reachable during the vmotion.

VT/PT are set, bios on both system matches, performed bios and nic firmware update.
both running same version of esxi build.

We've already tried several vmware kb's and EVC has been enabled.

Can someone provide us some help ?

More information added:

**General info Server A:**
[image]
**General info Server B:**
[image]

Some information of the network:

We have 4 nics on each of the two servers.

- 2 nics for network redundancy
- 2 nics for dedicated to storage and vmotion connectivity

on both servers the following settings match 100%: (cross checked it)

**First Screenshots are mgmt interfaces:**
[image]
[image]

**2nd screenshots are the Vswitch for storage and vmotion**

[image]
[image]

Both are using the same nic hardware and bios update.

Thank you

Comment: - validation is succesfull before migration
- vmotion only works when vm's are powered off

Comment: are both host DNS entries good? both forward and reverse?

Comment: Yes,
both network reachable and are able to ping the gateway and 8.8.8.8 and are able to resolve dns queries.

Comment: Please show the network configuration screenshot from the vSphere client, [as in this example](http://serverfault.com/questions/584303/network-configuration-for-vmware-w-vmotion-and-a-single-switch/584308#584308).

Comment: I've added the information in the original question.

Comment: What do the vmkernel and virtual machine logs say? Have you searched "Source detected that destination failed to resume" in VMware's knowledge base? There are quite some entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've solved this problem last week.
sorry for my late response.

We've been trying to setup our Storage and vmotion network as following doc:

http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2011/08/vsphere-50-storage-features-part-12-iscsi-multipathing-enhancements.html

We have created 2 vmkernel each using one of both physical interface who were added to the vswitch. To work as an active active interface setup, to be able to perform iscsi multipathing.

Eventually we removed the 2nd vmkernel added both physical interfaces to the one remaining vmkernel and let nic teaming do al the active active multipathing.

It solved our problem immediately.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

look to this information:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003734

The last action (change advanced settings, the Migration option in 2 hosts) work to me.

Comment: It is customary on Server Fault to include more than just a link to a good source in answers, in addition to the link also include the actual steps required to solve the original posters problem. Thanks in advance.